# How to solve $\sum\limits_{k=0}^{n-a-b}\binom{n-a-b}{k}(a+k-1)!(n-a-k)!$

Tags: probability, combinatorics, summation, binomial-coefficients

I'm solving a probability problem, and I've ended up with this sum:

$$\sum\limits_{k=0}^{n-a-b}\binom{n-a-b}{k}(a+k-1)!(n-a-k)!$$

WolframAlpha says I should get the answer $\frac{n!}{a\binom{a+b}{a}}$, but I don't see how to get there. I tried to get to something containing $\binom{a+k-1}{k}$ so that I could use the Hockey Stick Theorem, but I wasn't successful.

So any hints would be very welcome, thanks for any help

Comment: Certainly, if you divide by $n!,$ you get $$\frac{1}{n}\sum_k \frac{\binom{n-a-b}{k}}{\binom{n-1}{a+k-1}}.$$ Not sure how that helps, though.

Answer (score 5):

We seek to find a closed form of

$$(n-1)! \sum_{k=0}^{n-a-b} 
{n-a-b\choose k} {n-1\choose n-a-k}^{-1}$$

where $n\gt a+b$ and $a,b\ge 1.$

Recall from [MSE
4316307](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4316307/)  the
following identity which was proved there: with $1\le k\le n$

$$\frac{1}{k} {n\choose k}^{-1}
= [z^n] \log\frac{1}{1-z} (z-1)^{n-k}.$$

We get for our sum

$$(n-1)! \sum_{k=0}^{n-a-b} {n-a-b\choose k}
(n-a-k) [z^{n-1}] \log\frac{1}{1-z} (z-1)^{a-1+k}
\\ = (n-1)! \sum_{k=0}^{n-a-b} {n-a-b\choose k}
(k+b) [z^{n-1}] \log\frac{1}{1-z} (z-1)^{n-1-b-k}.$$

We get two pieces, the first is

$$b [z^{n-1}] \log\frac{1}{1-z} (z-1)^{n-1-b}
\sum_{k=0}^{n-a-b} {n-a-b\choose k} (z-1)^{-k}
\\ = b [z^{n-1}] \log\frac{1}{1-z} (z-1)^{n-1-b}
\left[1+\frac{1}{z-1}\right]^{n-a-b}
\\ = b [z^{a+b-1}] \log\frac{1}{1-z} (z-1)^{a-1}
\\ = {a+b-1\choose b}^{-1}.$$

The second is

$$ (n-a-b) [z^{n-1}] \log\frac{1}{1-z} (z-1)^{n-1-b}
\sum_{k=1}^{n-a-b} {n-a-b-1\choose k-1} (z-1)^{-k}
\\ =  (n-a-b) [z^{n-1}] \log\frac{1}{1-z} (z-1)^{n-2-b}
\sum_{k=0}^{n-a-b-1} {n-a-b-1\choose k} (z-1)^{-k}
\\ =  (n-a-b) [z^{n-1}] \log\frac{1}{1-z} (z-1)^{n-2-b}
\left[1+\frac{1}{z-1}\right]^{n-a-b-1}
\\ = (n-a-b) [z^{a+b}] \log\frac{1}{1-z} (z-1)^{a-1}
\\ = \frac{n-a-b}{b+1} {a+b\choose b+1}^{-1}.$$

Collecting everything we find

$$(n-1)! {a+b\choose b}^{-1}
\left[ \frac{a+b}{a} + \frac{n-a-b}{b+1} \frac{b+1}{a} \right]
\\ = \frac{n!}{a} {a+b\choose b}^{-1}.$$

This is the claim.

Comment: Very instructive answer. (+1)

Answer (score 3):

It seems to be the result of taking $x := a$, $y := b+1$, $z := 1$ and "$n$" $:= n - a - b$ in the [Rothe-Hagen identity](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rothe%E2%80%93Hagen_identity) (thank you for indirectly making me discover this complicated yet fascinating identity today).

This gives you, using $\displaystyle \frac{c}{d} \binom{d}{d - c} = \frac{c \cdot d!}{d \cdot c!(d-c)!} = \binom{d-1}{d - c}$ to simplify the formula:
$$\sum_{k = 0}^{n - a - b} \binom{a + k - 1}{k}\binom{n - a - k}{n - a - b - k} = \binom{n}{n - a - b}$$

Let's reorder all the factorials hidden in the binomials:
$$\begin{split}1 =& \frac{1}{\binom{n}{n - a - b}} \sum_{k = 0}^{n - a - b} \binom{a + k - 1}{k}\binom{n - a - k}{n - a - b - k}\\& = \frac{(a+b)!(n - a - b)!}{n!}\sum_{k = 0}^{n - a - b} \frac{(a + k - 1)!}{k!(a-1)!}\frac{(n - a - k)!}{(n - a - b - k)!b!}\\
& = \frac{1}{n!}\frac{(a+b)!}{(a-1)!b!} \sum_{k = 0}^{n - a - b} \frac{(n - a - b)!}{(n - a - b - k)!k!}(a + k - 1)!(n - a - k)!\\
& = \frac{a\binom{a+b}{a}}{n!} \sum_{k = 0}^{n - a - b} \binom{n - a - b}{k}(a + k - 1)!(n - a - k)!\end{split}$$
This finally grants:
$$\sum_{k = 0}^{n - a - b} \binom{n - a - b}{k}(a + k - 1)!(n - a - k)! = \frac{n!}{a\binom{a+b}{a}}$$

Comment: It's also interesting to see that here we have a Rothe-Hagen identity in disguise. (+1)

Answer (score 3):

> We obtain
> \begin{align*}
> \color{blue}{\sum_{k=0}^{n-a-b}}&\color{blue}{\binom{n-a-b}{k}(a+k-1)!(n-a-k)!}\\
> &=(n-1)!\sum_{k=0}^{n-a-b}\binom{n-a-b}{k}\binom{n-1}{n-a-k}^{-1}\tag{1}\\
> &=n!\sum_{k=0}^{n-a-b}\binom{n-a-b}{k}\int_{0}^1z^{n-a-k}(1-z)^{a+k-1}\,dz\tag{2}\\
> &=n!\int_{0}^1z^{n-a}(1-z)^{a-1}\sum_{k=0}^{n-a-b}\binom{n-a-b}{k}\left(\frac{1-z}{z}\right)^k\,dz\\
> &=n!\int_{0}^1z^{n-a}(1-z)^{a-1}\left(1+\frac{1-z}{z}\right)^{n-a-b}\,dz\\
> &=n!\int_{0}^1z^b(1-z)^{a-1}\,dz\\
> &=\frac{n!}{a+b}\binom{a+b-1}{b}^{-1}\tag{2}\\
> &\,\,\color{blue}{=\frac{n!}{a}\binom{a+b}{a}^{-1}}\tag{3}
> \end{align*}
> in accordance with the claim and other answers.

*Comment:*

- In (1) we use a representation using binomial coefficients.
- In (2) we write the reciprocal of a binomial coefficient using the *[beta function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Beta_function)*
  \begin{align*}
  \binom{n}{k}^{-1}=(n+1)\int_0^1z^k(1-z)^{n-k}\,dz
  \end{align*}
- In (3) we use the binomial identity
  \begin{align*}
  (a+b)\binom{a+b-1}{b}=(a+b)\binom{a+b-1}{a-1}=a\binom{a+b}{a}
  \end{align*}

Comment: The Beta function is more compact here. (+1). I wrote the answer below expressly with the goal of using formal power series only.

Comment: (+1) I knew there had to be a way simpler and way clearer answer than mine, nice use of the Beta function! Same goes for Marko Riedel's answer (+1 too)

Comment: @MarkoRiedel: I already had the assumption that a thematic approach has been chosen here. :-)

Comment: @epi163sqrt I have a nice computation [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4552694/) that you might enjoy seeing.