# Value of $ {_3F_2}{\left(1,n+\frac32,1-r;\frac32,n+2;1\right)} $

Tags: sequences-and-series, binomial-coefficients, closed-form, hypergeometric-function

This sum can be calculated using a CAS as a product of Gamma and Generalized Hypergeometric functions

$$\displaystyle \sum_{k=0}^n \frac {\dbinom{n}k \dbinom{n+r}k}{\dbinom{2n}{2k}} = \dfrac{(2n+1) \Gamma(n+r-1){_3F_2}{\left(1,n+\dfrac32,1-r;\dfrac32,n+2;1\right)}}{\Gamma(n+2) \Gamma(r) } $$

Is it possible to further simplify it?

**Update**: I found this problem on [Western Number Theory Problems 1993](https://wcnt.files.wordpress.com/2018/02/wcnt-problems-1993.pdf), the only case covered was $ r=1 $, pointing that a possible approach was through the use of the generating function for the Catalan number. I had no idea how to approach the general problem, other then trying to use a relation similar to [Dougall's Hypergeometric Theorem](https://proofwiki.org/wiki/Dougall%27s_Hypergeometric_Theorem), but found nothing suitable, so thanks to @Marko Riedel for showing his resolution method!

Comment: @Moo now it should be ok. Thanks

Comment: This generalized hypergeometric function can in fact be simplified to a finite sum of ratios of binomial coefficients. In other words, the sum you started with! =p

Comment: The question is lacking context in its present form.

Comment: There is this [meta link](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/9959/) on how to ask a good question.

Comment: I believe $\Gamma(n+r-1)$ in the numerator should actually be $\Gamma(n+r+1)$.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Update.**  OP asked  for a  complete proof  and that  is
indeed what we will present.

Supposing we start from

$$\sum_{k=0}^n {n\choose k} {n+r\choose k} {2n\choose 2k}^{-1}.$$

Write

$${n+r\choose k} = \frac{(n+r)!}{k! \times (n+r-k)!}
= {n+r\choose n} \frac{n! \times r!}{k! \times (n+r-k)!}
\\ = {n+r\choose n} {n\choose k} {n-k+r\choose r}^{-1}.$$

Furthermore

$${n\choose k}^2 {2n\choose 2k}^{-1}
= {2n\choose n}^{-1} 
\frac{(2k)! \times (2n-2k)!}{(n-k)!^2\times k!^2}
\\ = {2n\choose n}^{-1} {2k\choose k} {2n-2k\choose n-k}.$$

We thus have for our sum

$${n+r\choose n} {2n\choose n}^{-1}
\sum_{k=0}^n {2k\choose k} {2n-2k\choose n-k} 
{n-k+r\choose r}^{-1}.$$

Recall from [MSE
4316307](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4316307/)  the
following identity which was proved there: with $1\le k\le n$

$$\frac{1}{k} {n\choose k}^{-1}
= [v^n] \log\frac{1}{1-v} (v-1)^{n-k}.$$

We can re-write this as

$${n-1\choose k-1}^{-1} = 
n [v^n] \log\frac{1}{1-v} (v-1)^{n-k}.$$

We have for the sum without the scalar in front

$$\sum_{k=0}^n {2k\choose k} {2n-2k\choose n-k} 
(n+1-k+r) [v^{n+1-k+r}] \log \frac{1}{1-v}
(v-1)^{n-k}.$$

The contribution from $v$ is

$$\;\underset{v}{\mathrm{res}}\;
\frac{1}{v^{n+2-k+r}}
\log\frac{1}{1-v} (v-1)^{n-k}.$$

Now put $v/(1-v)=z$ so that $v=z/(1+z)$ and $dv= 1/(1+z)^2 \; dz$
to obtain

$$\;\underset{z}{\mathrm{res}}\;
\frac{1}{z^{n+2-k+r}} (-1)^{n-k} (1+z)^{r+2}
\log (1+z) \frac{1}{(1+z)^2}.$$

We thus find for the sum

$$ (-1)^n [z^{n+1+r}] \log(1+z) (1+z)^r
\\ \times \sum_{k=0}^n {2k\choose k} {2n-2k\choose n-k} 
(n+1-k+r) (-1)^k z^k
\\ =  (-1)^r [z^{n+1+r}] \log\frac{1}{1-z} (1-z)^r
\\ \times \sum_{k=0}^n {2k\choose k} {2n-2k\choose n-k} 
(n+1-k+r) z^k
\\ = [z^{n+1+r}] \log\frac{1}{1-z} (z-1)^r
\\ \times \sum_{k=0}^n {2k\choose k} {2n-2k\choose n-k} 
(n+1-k+r) z^k.$$

We now get two pieces.

#### First piece

This is

$$(n+1+r) [z^{n+1+r}] \log\frac{1}{1-z} (z-1)^r
\\ \times \sum_{k=0}^n {2k\choose k} {2n-2k\choose n-k} z^k
\\ = (n+1+r) [z^{n+1+r}] \log\frac{1}{1-z} (z-1)^r
[w^n] \frac{1}{\sqrt{1-4wz}} \frac{1}{\sqrt{1-4w}}.$$

The square root yields

$$[w^n] \frac{1}{\sqrt{1-4w-4w(z-1)}} \frac{1}{\sqrt{1-4w}}
\\ = [w^n] \frac{1}{\sqrt{1-4w(z-1)/(1-4w)}} \frac{1}{1-4w}
\\ = [w^n] \sum_{p=0}^n
{2p\choose p} \frac{w^p (z-1)^p}{(1-4w)^{p+1}}
= \sum_{p=0}^n
{2p\choose p} (z-1)^p 4^{n-p} {n\choose p}.$$

Applying the logarithm

$$\sum_{p=0}^n
{2p\choose p} 4^{n-p} {n\choose p}
{n+r\choose n-p}^{-1}.$$

Next observe that

$${n\choose p} {n+r\choose n-p}^{-1}
= \frac{n! \times (r+p)!}{p! \times (n+r)!}
\\ = {n+r\choose n}^{-1} {r+p\choose r}$$

which produces

$${n+r\choose n}^{-1}
\sum_{p=0}^n {2p\choose p} 4^{n-p} {r+p\choose r}.$$

#### Second piece

This is

$$- [z^{n+1+r}] \log\frac{1}{1-z} (z-1)^r
\\ \times \sum_{k=0}^n k {2k\choose k} {2n-2k\choose n-k} z^k
\\ = - [z^{n+1+r}] \log\frac{1}{1-z} (z-1)^r
[w^n] \frac{2wz}{\sqrt{1-4wz}^3} \frac{1}{\sqrt{1-4w}}.$$

The square root yields

$$[w^n] \frac{2wz}{\sqrt{1-4w-4w(z-1)}^3} \frac{1}{\sqrt{1-4w}}
\\ = z [w^{n}] \frac{2w}{\sqrt{1-4w(z-1)/(1-4w)}^3} 
\frac{1}{(1-4w)^2}
\\ = \frac{z}{z-1} [w^{n}] \frac{2w(z-1)/(1-4w)}
{\sqrt{1-4w(z-1)/(1-4w)}^3} 
\frac{1}{1-4w}
\\ = \frac{z}{z-1} [w^{n}] \sum_{p=0}^n
p {2p\choose p} \frac{w^p (z-1)^p}{(1-4w)^{p+1}}
= \frac{z}{z-1} \sum_{p=0}^n
p {2p\choose p} (z-1)^p 4^{n-p} {n\choose p}.$$

Applying the logarithm and the sign

$$- \frac{1}{n+r} \sum_{p=0}^n
p {2p\choose p} 4^{n-p} {n\choose p}
{n+r-1\choose n-p}^{-1}.$$

Next observe that

$$\frac{1}{n+r} {n\choose p} {n+r-1\choose n-p}^{-1}
= \frac{n! \times (r+p-1)!}{p! \times (n+r)!}
\\ = \frac{1}{r+p} {n+r\choose n}^{-1} {r+p\choose r}$$

which produces

$$- {n+r\choose n}^{-1}
\sum_{p=0}^n \frac{p}{r+p}
{2p\choose p} 4^{n-p} {r+p\choose r}.$$

#### Join the two pieces

We join the two pieces and activate the scalars to get

$${2n\choose n}^{-1}
\sum_{p=0}^n \frac{r}{r+p}
{2p\choose p} 4^{n-p} {r+p\choose r}.$$

For this to hold we need $r\ge 1.$ We further obtain

$${2n\choose n}^{-1}
\sum_{p=0}^n
{2p\choose p} 4^{n-p} {r+p-1\choose r-1}.$$

Working with the sum

$$4^n [z^n] \frac{1}{1-z} \sum_{p\ge 0} z^p
{2p\choose p} 4^{-p} {r+p-1\choose r-1}
\\ = 4^n [z^n] \frac{1}{1-z} 
[w^{r-1}] (1+w)^{r-1} \sum_{p\ge 0} z^p
{2p\choose p} 4^{-p} (1+w)^p
\\ = 4^n [z^n] \frac{1}{1-z} 
[w^{r-1}] (1+w)^{r-1}
\frac{1}{\sqrt{1-z(1+w)}}
\\ = 4^n [z^n] \frac{1}{(1-z)^{3/2}} 
[w^{r-1}] (1+w)^{r-1}
\frac{1}{\sqrt{1-wz/(1-z)}}
\\ = 4^n [z^n] \frac{1}{(1-z)^{3/2}} 
\sum_{p=0}^{r-1} {r-1\choose r-1-p} {2p\choose p}
4^{-p} \frac{z^p}{(1-z)^p}
\\ = 4^n 
\sum_{p=0}^{r-1} {r-1\choose p} {2p\choose p}
4^{-p} {n+1/2\choose n-p}.$$

The last binomial coefficient is zero for a negative lower index by
construction. We have for $r\ge 1$ the closed form

$$\bbox[5px,border:2px solid #00A000]{
4^n {2n\choose n}^{-1}
\sum_{p=0}^{r-1} {r-1\choose p} {2p\choose p}
4^{-p} {n+1/2\choose n-p}.}$$

This gives e.g. for $r=1$

$$4^n {2n\choose n}^{-1} {n+1/2\choose n}.$$

We get for $r=2$

$$4^n {2n\choose n}^{-1} 
\left[ {n+1/2\choose n} + \frac{1}{2} {n+1/2\choose n-1} \right].$$

One more example is $r=3$ which yields

$$4^n {2n\choose n}^{-1} 
\left[ {n+1/2\choose n} + {n+1/2\choose n-1} 
+ \frac{3}{8} {n+1/2\choose n-2} \right].$$

Last example is $r=4$

$$4^n {2n\choose n}^{-1} 
\left[ {n+1/2\choose n} + \frac{3}{2} {n+1/2\choose n-1} 
+ \frac{9}{8} {n+1/2\choose n-2} 
+ \frac{5}{16} {n+1/2\choose n-3} \right].$$

#### The case of $r=0$

We have from the introduction

$${n+r\choose n} {2n\choose n}^{-1}
\sum_{k=0}^n {2k\choose k} {2n-2k\choose n-k} 
{n-k+r\choose r}^{-1}.$$

Evaluate at $r=0$ to get

$${2n\choose n}^{-1}
\sum_{k=0}^n {2k\choose k} {2n-2k\choose n-k} 
\\ = {2n\choose n}^{-1}
[z^n] \frac{1}{\sqrt{1-4z}} \frac{1}{\sqrt{1-4z}}
= {2n\choose n}^{-1}
[z^n] \frac{1}{1-4z} 
= 4^n {2n\choose n}^{-1}.$$

Comment: Thank you! Yes, I'm interested in reading the proof. I found the summatory on here https://wcnt.files.wordpress.com/2018/02/wcnt-problems-1993.pdf pag 7. Does it has a combinatorial interpretation?

Comment: You need to move this comment into your post. Explain where you found the problem and what you have tried. As it is your question will probably be closed. That's most likely why it has received no up votes.

Comment: I updated the post, thanks for your help!

Comment: OK. Ideally you would also make an attempt to see where it takes you and document your work. We can re-write the hypergeometric term.

Comment: Honestly I looked for theorems like this one https://proofwiki.org/wiki/Dougall%27s_Hypergeometric_Theorem to convert the hypergeometric term in Gamma product, but found nothing suitable. Do you used Egorychev method to solve that?

Comment: Please move the above into the post and explain what you found and where progress was halted. With that I think I can post the proof (Egorychev method) and hope the question is now in good shape not to be closed.

Comment: @MarkoRiedel: Interesting and instructive post. (+1)